# Create associated records in model after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, oncreate, associated-object

I have a model, MyModel, which should, after it is created, created associated records of type MyAssociation. I need to run code like the below after a create on the MyModel:

```
myass = MyAssociation.new
myass.mymodel_id = self.id
myass.save
```

What is the best method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to use Rails [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), in this case `after_create` which will execute after successful creation of the original object. Something like this:

```
class MyModel

  after_create :create_associations

  def create_associations
    myass = MyAssociation.new
    myass.mymodel_id = self.id
    myass.save
  end
end
```

Comment: When the save is run in this case, it doesn't seem to save to the database.

Comment: @steventnorris well I don't know what kind of validations your association model has, but if it's not saving there's a chance a validation is failing. try saving with a bang, `myass.save!` and see if it pops an error

Comment: I have tried that, no change